# Как сверстать как на картинке?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, sass

Как сверстать как на картинке?

```css
.doc__img
 margin-top: 50px
 width: 95px;
 height: 116px;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 5px rgba(29, 70, 48, 0.75)
 background-color: #43a06d;
 display: -webkit-flex
 display: -moz-flex
 display: -ms-flex
 display: -o-flex
 display: flex
 align-items: center
 justify-content: center
 font-size: 60px
 border-radius: 5px
 border-top-left-radius: 13px 
 position: relative
 overflow: hidden
 background: linear-gradient(#fff right, #43a06d bottom);
.doc__img:after
 content: ''
 position: absolute
 width: 0
 height: 0
 border-top: 15px solid transparent
 border-right: 15px solid rgba(29, 70, 48, 0.75)
 left: -5px
 top: -1px
```

```html
<div class="doc__img">
    <img src="https://www.google.ru/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fkomiwiki.syktsu.ru%2Fimages%2Fthumb%2F4%2F40%2F%25D0%2594%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BA.JPG%2F150px-%25D0%2594%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BA.JPG&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fkomiwiki.syktsu.ru%2Findex.php%2F%25D0%2594%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BA%25D1%2583%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BD%25D1%2582._%25D0%2592%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B4%25D1%258B_%25D0%25B8_%25D1%2584%25D1%2583%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BA%25D1%2586%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B8.&docid=eMsizezWalTdhM&tbnid=lzaXrk3Gk9DfjM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjDy9ek8MncAhWBuywKHbP9DkYQMwi_ASgGMAY..i&w=150&h=191&bih=974&biw=1920&q=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82&ved=0ahUKEwjDy9ek8MncAhWBuywKHbP9DkYQMwi_ASgGMAY&iact=mrc&uact=8">

</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И что тут нужно сверстать?

Comment: как на картинке :) внутри красного прямоугольника ( я выделил красным прямоугольником)

Comment: И еще не знаю как над Heading сделать 2 фото с такой тенью

Comment: Спасите и сохраните меня от этого страшного макета

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот первый пример

```css
.inner{position:fixed;}


.border{width:72px;height:52px;z-index:-1;top:0px;}


.wrapper{width:70px;top:1px;left:1px;}


.container {background:rgb(226,226,226);text-align:center;}

.bcontainer{background:black;width:71px;height:41px;}
.abc {
    width: 60px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(226,226,226);
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.ab{    width: 61px;
    border-bottom: 11px solid black;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="wrapper inner">
    <div class="abc"></div>
    <div class="container">I AM A TAB<div>
</div>
<div class="border inner">
    <div class="ab"></div>
    <div class="bcontainer"><div>
</div>
</div>
```

Вот ссылка на другой пример:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248443/is-it-possible-to-create-an-angled-corner-in-css - разбирайтесь

Comment: ок спасибо за помощь